# Навигация по сайту

Tags: html, css

Как кожно сверстать это навигационное меню, чтобы оно не разъезжалось, и было всё ровно, помогите, пожалуйста.

[image]

Comment: Как-то вы вопросы задаете абстрактно. Что значит "*не разьезжалось, и было всё ровно*"? И судя по скрину, я так понимаю, что вам надо сверстать, используя графику? Или только CSS?

Comment: padding'ами. для :hover - вешаете фон на бакгранд.

Comment: нужно на чистом css3 без картинок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если CSS3, то вот [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/uvX33/). Только ж вы понимаете, что в осле это работать не будет? А Chrome, FireFox и др. - гуд

Comment: Спасибо Вам!